# YouTube Direct via Webcam?

Tags: youtube, webcam

Is it possible for users to record and upload a video from their webcam with YouTube Direct (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/ytdirect.html) or is the only option to upload a file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Only upload, sry. (The best solution I found this far is nimbb, a payed service, and you have to build the youtube integration yourself)